# For all sets $A, B$ and $C$, if $A \setminus B \subseteq C$ and $B \setminus C \subseteq A$ then $C \setminus A \subseteq B.$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> Prove or disprove: For all sets $A, B$ and $C$, if $A \setminus B \subseteq C$ and $B \setminus C \subseteq A$ then $C \setminus A \subseteq B.$

I cant figure this out someone please help.

Comment: Draw a picture.

Comment: Please add what your thoughts are about the question. As it stands the question doesn't fit the rules described in the [help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 2):

It's false: if you take $A=B$, the premises are true whatever $C$, yet if $C$ is not  contained in $A$, $C-A$ is certainly not contained in $A$.

Comment: #Bernard You forgot about if $A=B=C=\emptyset$.

Comment: If $A=B$, $A-B==\varnothing$, which is included in $C$, $B-C=A-C$ is a subset of $A$. What's wrong with my counter-example?

Comment: Certainly $\emptyset-\emptyset$ is contained in $\emptyset$.

Comment: I understand better what you mean now! I've added this restriction. Thanks!

Comment: Still, if $C$ is contained in $A$ then $C\setminus A$ is $\emptyset$ and is contained in $A$.

Comment: @Somos: You're right. It's crazy sometimes  the number of implicit hypotheses we forget to write! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

here is a counterexample

$$A=\{1,2,3\} $$
$$B=\{1,3\} $$
$$C=\{1,2,4\} $$

$$A-B=\{2\} \subset  C$$
$$B-C=\{3\} \subset A$$
$$C-A=\{4\} $$

Answer (score 0):

False. $A=B=\emptyset$ and $C$ is not empty is a counterexmaple,
and more generally if $A=B$ and $C\setminus A$ is not empty.